# How to copy maven parameters to another workspace?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have plenty of different Maven parameters as of now for running different configurations.. Now the problem is I want to switch to another machine, so there I can take my code for GIT, but I am not able to copy all the Maven run configuration. I have around 50 such parameters... Is there any way by which we can do something like export/import? Is there any other work-around? Thanks in advance.

Here is the screenshot of one maven command. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that screen is a "Launch configuration", then you can try:

```
Go to File > Export... > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations
```

You should be able to export said configuration as a file. Even consider adding it to your Git repo.
And then import it back in your new Eclipse

```
Go to File > Import... > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations
```